# Javascript Array Erroring Out

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array that seems to error out after 1 iteration.  I am querying a database (orders) and returning the values.  If only 1 set of data is returned from the query, it works, but if more than one I error out on myOrders[1].  I recognize this has something to do with me only declaring one row in the array, but I do not know how large the array will need to be (as the query could be 1 or many), so what is the right way to avoid getting an error on this iteration on i = 1?

```
var myOrders = [
    { "Date": " ", "Order": " ", "Units": " ", "Cost": " " },

    ];

    var o = orders.orders;
    var oq = o.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < oq; i++) {
         myOrders[i].Date = o[i].pickupDate;
         myOrders[i].Order = o[i].laundry;
         myOrders[i].Units = o[i].quantity;
         myOrders[i].Cost = o[i].amount;
        };
```

Thank you for any help you can provide!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this    . Here myOrders will be created dynamically based on the o.

```
var myOrders = [];
    var o = orders.orders;
    var oq = o.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < oq; i++) {
const someObject = {};
        someObject.Date = o[i].pickupDate;
         someObject.Order = o[i].laundry;
         someObject.Units = o[i].quantity;
         someObject.Cost = o[i].amount;
    myOrders.push(someObject)
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

You have only one element in myOrder on second iteration `myOrders[i]` will be undefined, so `myOrder[i].someProperty` will throw an error.

You can just use a map function instead simply and map the values to new keys

```
let myOrders = o.map(({pickupDate, laundry, quantity, amount})=> ({Date, Order, Units, Cost}))
```

Comment: o.map - are you saying that will map the entire results in one line of code to the array?

Comment: @Mr.Data yes, it will

Comment: Why would myOrders[i] be undefined?  Your code does not seem to work for me nothing is getting written to to the array.

Comment: @Mr.Data did you read the answer properly, your why is answered in first line itself. can you post the code you're trying.

Comment: @Mr.Data can you post how your `o` looks like, also you need to read my answer's first line for the answer of why not your questions first line 